# BigQuery: Consolidate subselect into one row by date

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, google-bigquery

I'm trying to have a BigQuery query result, which contains a subquery, return one row instead of two.  I'm querying log files so all the data I need is in the same field.  An example of the data in the field is as follow:

```
/?cv=p15.0.9350&ctyp=sp&bits=64&os_bits=64&hl=fr&hl=fr&os=win&osv=6.2
```

The query I've been working on is below:

```
SELECT day, Win, Mac 
  FROM
    (SELECT DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT protoPayload.resource) AS Win
     FROM [su_dashboard_streamed_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20150424]
     WHERE protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'ctyp=sp'
     GROUP BY day),
    (SELECT DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT protoPayload.resource) AS Mac
     FROM [request_log_20150424]
     WHERE protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'ctyp=sm'
     GROUP BY day)
ORDER BY day
```

Currently the query above returns:

```
Row day Win Mac  
1   2015-04-24  160516  null     
2   2015-04-24  null    109547
```

I'd like the result to be:

```
Row day Win Mac
1 2015-04-24 160516 109547
```

Is there a way to do this?  If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `JOIN` the two sub-selects instead of unioning them.  In BigQuery, [a comma within a `FROM` clause indicates a union](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#from):

> Note: Unlike many other SQL-based systems, BigQuery uses the comma syntax to indicate table unions, not joins.

If you `JOIN` on the day field, then you can compact the two rows into a single one with something like the following:

```
SELECT table_1.day as day, table_1.Win as Win, table_2.Mac AS Mac
  FROM
    (SELECT DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT protoPayload.resource) AS Win
     FROM [su_dashboard_streamed_logs.appengine_googleapis_com_request_log_20150424]
     WHERE protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'ctyp=sp'
     GROUP BY day) AS table_1
  JOIN
    (SELECT DATE(metadata.timestamp) AS day, COUNT(DISTINCT protoPayload.resource) AS Mac
     FROM [request_log_20150424]
     WHERE protoPayload.resource CONTAINS 'ctyp=sm'
     GROUP BY day) AS table_2
  ON table_1.day = table_2.day
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Thank you so much Danny, I've been trying to do this for over a day.  You solved a major headache for me.  Thanks again!!